# phpunit mock a method that should return an exception

Tags: xml, exception, mocking, phpunit

I have a method in a class that parses some xml.
If it finds the tag **< status >failure< /status >**, it returns an exception.

I want to build a unittest that checks this method does return an exception when the status=failure.

For the moment, I fail to get it done using **phpunit** and **MOCKING**?

Example:

```
<?php
$mock = $this->getMock('Service_Order_Http', array('getResponse'));
        $mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getResponse')
            ->will($this->throwException(new Exception()));

        $e = null;
        try {
            $mock->getResponse();
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
        $this->assertTrue($e instanceof Exception, "Method getResponse should have thrown an exception");

//phpunit sends back: PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed asserting that exception of type "Exception" is thrown.
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: After re-reading your question; is "Service_Order_Http" the class you're trying to test?

Comment: Yes, "Service_Order_Http" is the class I am mocking. 
The one that contains the xml parsing method.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully that's what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of mocks in unit testing.

A mock is used to substitute a dependency of the class you're actually trying to test.

This is probably worth a read: [What is Object Mocking and when do I need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314/what-is-object-mocking-and-when-do-i-need-it)

I think you're actually looking for something more along these lines with your test:

```
<?php

    // This is a class that Service_Order_Http depends on.
    // Since we don't want to test the implementation of this class
    // we create a mock of it.
    $dependencyMock = $this->getMock('Dependency_Class');

    // Create an instance of the Service_Order_Http class,
    // passing in the dependency to the constructor (dependency injection).
    $serviceOrderHttp = new Service_Order_Http($dependencyMock);

    // Create or load in some sample XML to test with 
    // that contains the tag you're concerned with
    $sampleXml = "<xml><status>failure</status></xml>";

    // Give the sample XML to $serviceOrderHttp, however that's done
    $serviceOrderHttp->setSource($sampleXml);

    // Set the expectation of the exception
    $this->setExpectedException('Exception');

    // Run the getResponse method.
    // Your test will fail if it doesn't throw
    // the exception.
    $serviceOrderHttp->getResponse();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, that works, but what about my xml parsing?
getResponse() should only return an exception if the xml tag < status >failure < /status >

In your case, it always returns an excpetion.

Comment: thx again, this is almost it, as I dont have a setSource() :)
I need to pass $sampleXml without using setSource(), this is why I thought about mocking.

Comment: How does Service_Order_Http get the xml during normal operation?

Comment: A protected method using Zend_Http_Client.

The protected method sets the response xml into a protected var, which will be prased by the getResponse()

Comment: The one test should test the failure in status, and return the exception.  Another test case is then done, with another possible mock object, to handle success.